# How can I utilize Polymorphism with List objects?

Tags: c#, list, generics, polymorphism

Here's a brief overview of my following problem, in case I am approaching this incorrectly:

I have a list of customers, purchase orders, and invoices all displayed in datagrids. I would like to verify that what is displayed in these grids matches the lists I actually have (this is for an automated testing application). The way I am trying to handle it, is by going through each table, and within that going through each row of objects, and comparing it to the objects in my lists (hence the actual/expected variables).

I have an application that has multiple `List` objects, for example:

```
List<PurchaseOrder>
List<Customer>
List<Invoice>
```

And I want to be able to write a loop that can manipulate each of these lists, rather than having one foreach statement for each list. I have multiple tables that show each object (a PO table, a customer table, etc) and I want to iterate all of them as such:

```
foreach(Table t in Tables)
{
    List<??> tableItems = new List<??>; // Perhaps this should be `object tableItems;`?

    switch(t.Name)
    {
        case "PurchaseOrder":
            tableItems = purchaseOrders; // purchaseOrders is a List<PurchaseOrder> object
            break;
        case "Customer":
            tableItems = customers; // List<Customer>
            break;
        case "Invoice":
            tableItems = invoices; // List<Invoice>
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Now I want to get the count of items, to loop through
    for(int i = 0; i < tableItems.Count; i++)
    {
        // Do work
    }
}
```

However, I can't figure out the right way to use the polymorphism here. If I make tableItems a List of Objects (`List<Object>`), I will get the error `Cannot convert type of List<PurchaseOrder> to List<Object>`.

If I cast tableItems to the `Object` class, I can't call the .Count field.

**EDIT:** I understand I could solve this easily by putting my for loop inside each case statement -

```
case "PurchaseOrder":
    tableItems = purchaseOrders;
    for(int i = 0; i < tableItems.Count; i++)
    {
        // Do Work
    }
    break;
```

But I would like a way to extract that for loop.

**EDIT 2**
Here's another example of the code I'm using now and what I would like to do with it but can't quite figure out:

```
foreach(Table t in Tables)
    {
    List<??> tableItems = new List<??>; // Perhaps this should be `object tableItems;`?

    string expectedItem;
    string actualItem = t.rows[currentRow].Cells[column1].Value.ToString();

    switch(t.Name)
    {
        case "PurchaseOrder":
            for(int i = 0; i < purchaseOrders.Count; i++)
            {
                PurchaseOrder p = purchaseOrders[i];
                expectedItem = p.POValue1;
            }
            break;
        case "Customer":
            for(int i = 0; i < customers.Count; i++)
            {
                Customer c = customers[i];
                expectedItem = c.CustValue1;
            }
            break;
        case "Invoice":
            for(int i = 0; i < invoices.Count; i++)
            {
                Invoice inv = invoices[i];
                expectedItem = inv.InvoiceValue1;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // I would prefer to do something like this:
    switch(t.Name)
    {
        case "PurchaseOrder":
            actualItem = purchaseOrders; // List<PurchaseOrder> object
            break;
        case "Customer":
            actualItem = customers; // List<Customer>
            break;
        case "Invoice":
            actualItem = invoices; // List<Invoice>
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < tableItems.Count; i++)
    {
        (object) o = tableItems[i];
        switch(object)
        {
            case "PurchaseOrder":
                expectedItem = o.POValue1;
                break;
            case "Customer":
                expectedItem = o.CustValue1;
                break;
            case "Invoice":
                expectedItem = inv.InvoiceValue1;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do your `PurchaseOrder`, `Customer` and `Invoice` classes have an interface or a base class?

Comment: No, there really is nothing in common between them. I suppose I could add one, but it wouldn't be worth it for the few lines of code I'd actually be saving.

Comment: I am under the impression you are confusing Polymorphism and Generics? Are are familiar with both? In addition what is the table type at the beginning?

Comment: What kind of work are you doing with the items?

Comment: please change polymorphism to generics

Comment: I am familiar with both. I thought this was a polymorphism issue because I am trying to merge multiple classes into one list. Each table displays a list of it's respected object. So I have a customer table that shows Customer objects, a PurchaseOrder table that shows PO objects, and so on. I want to loop through each table (all are 3 columns wide, by coincidence) and read each of those columns and compare them to a customer object, or a po object, dependant on the current table in question. I will edit the answer with more thorough code that may help.

Comment: besides you can always call the count property of any List<T>. I am sry I really have to downvote on that question.

Comment: polymorphism would include some class hierarchy and a variable.

Comment: This might be a better basis for the problem: I have a list of customers, purchase orders, and invoices all displayed in datagrids. I would like to verify that what is displayed in these grids matches the lists I actually have (this is for an automated testing application). The way I am trying to handle it, is by going through each table, and within that going through each object, and comparing it to the objects in my lists (hence the actual/expected variables).

Comment: Does the table only contain strings or also other types?

Comment: @Nico each table contains two strings and one date. I am writing an automated test for someone else's application, so I have to work with the UI elements I'm given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of intermingling code that handles all tables simultaneously, I would solve the problem one table at a time.

Each object type dictates what is displayed in the table. This will always be a tuple of any kind of objects. So it is sufficient if the validation method gets these display objects instead of the source:

```
//More or less pseudo code
bool Validate(Table table, object[][] displayObjects)
{
    for each iItem
        for each iColumn
            if(table.Rows[iItem].Columns[iColumn].Equals(displayObjects[iItem][iColumn])
                //everything is fine
            else
                //there is a validation error
}
```

This leaves us with the task to transform any list of objects to its respective list of display objects. This can be performed with LINQ:

```
Validate(POTable, POList.Select(po => 
                new object[] { po.Property1, po.Property2, po.Property3 }).ToArray());
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help on this one, I got it all figured out!

Answer (score 1):

OP. This seems like an XY question here. Your domain problem is that you would like to automate comparing a `DataSet` with a collection of collections of objects. You have noted that there are commonalities in the code for comparing `PurchaseOrder`s with the `PurchaseOrder` table and `Invoice`s with the `Invoice` table. I suggest you read up on design patterns and see if there is a pattern that would work with your problem. 
The Strategy pattern looks to be pretty good for it...

```
public bool TableCollectionCompare<T>(
       Compare<DataRow, T> comparer, 
       DataTable table, 
       ICollection<T> objects);
```

Another pattern would be an `abstract class` to do the loading of the Table and the collection...

```
public abstract class TableCollectionComparer<T>
{
    protected bool Compare(DataRow row, T item);

    public bool Compare(DataTable table, ICollection<T> item)
    {
        foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
             ...
             bool result = Compare(row, item);
        }
    }
}
```